# Problem while implementing join of two dataset in google cloud dataflow using Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I was trying to implement SQL on two dataset on google cloud storage using apache beam by following Apache Beam documentation https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/walkthrough/

But i am ended with the below exception :
 An exception occured while executing the Java class. org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements
.via(Lorg/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/SimpleFunction;)Lorg/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/MapElements;

I tried changing Beam-sdk-version and other code changes but none of them worked .

```
package com.nitesh.gcp.feature;

import org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.options.DataflowPipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.sql.SqlTransform;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.Schema;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollectionTuple;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.Row;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TupleTag;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class beamSQL1 {

    public static final String EMPHEADER = "empno,ename,job,mgr,hiredate,sal,comm,deptno";
    public static final String DEPTHEADER = "deptno,dname,location";
    public static final Schema EMPSCHEMA = Schema.builder()
            .addStringField("empno")
            .addStringField("ename")
            .addStringField("job")
            .addStringField("mgr")
            .addStringField("hiredate")
            .addStringField("sal")
            .addStringField("comm")
            .addStringField("deptno")
            .build();
    public static final Schema DEPTSCHEMA = Schema.builder()
            .addStringField("deptno")
            .addStringField("dname")
            .addStringField("location")
            .build();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PipelineOptionsFactory.register(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
        DataflowPipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory
                .fromArgs(args)
                .withValidation()
                .as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);

        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);
        PCollection<String> employee = pipeline.apply("Read From GCS", TextIO.read().from("gs://amazon-test/sqlData/employee.txt"));
        PCollection<String> department = pipeline.apply("Read From GCS", TextIO.read().from("gs://amazon-test/sqlData/department.txt"));
        PCollection<Row> employeeRow = employee.apply("Transform To Row", ParDo.of(new RowParDo())).setRowSchema(EMPSCHEMA);
        PCollection<Row> departmentRow = department.apply("Transform To Row", ParDo.of(new RowParDoForDept())).setRowSchema(DEPTSCHEMA);
        PCollectionTuple output = PCollectionTuple.of(new TupleTag<>("emp"), employeeRow).and(new TupleTag<>("dept"), departmentRow);


        output.apply(
                SqlTransform.query(
                        // "SELECT emp.empno,emp.ename,dept.deptno,dept.dname FROM emp JOIN dept ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno"))
                        "SELECT * from emp JOIN dept ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno"))

                /* p2.apply("Transform Sql", SqlTransform.query(
                         "SELECT * " +
                                 "FROM PCOLLECTION order by sal desc LIMIT 14")
                 )*/
                .apply("TransForm To String", ParDo.of(new RowToString()))
                .apply("Write To GCS", TextIO.write().to("gs://amazon-test/sqlData/output/outputSql.csv").withoutSharding());

        pipeline.run();
    }

    //ParDo for String -> Row (SQL)
    public static class RowParDo extends DoFn<String, Row> {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            if (!c.element().equalsIgnoreCase(EMPHEADER)) {
                String[] vals = c.element().split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
                Row appRow = Row
                        .withSchema(EMPSCHEMA)
                        .addValues(vals[0], vals[1], vals[2], vals[3], vals[4], vals[5], vals[6], vals[7])
                        .build();
                c.output(appRow);
            }
        }
    }

    //ParDo for Row (SQL) -> String
    public static class RowToString extends DoFn<Row, String> {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            String line = c.element().getValues()
                    .stream()
                    .map(Object::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            c.output(line);
        }
    }

    //ParDo for String -> Row (SQL)
    public static class RowParDoForDept extends DoFn<String, Row> {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            if (!c.element().equalsIgnoreCase(DEPTHEADER)) {
                String[] vals = c.element().split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
                Row appRow = Row
                        .withSchema(DEPTSCHEMA)
                        .addValues(vals[0], vals[1], vals[2])
                        .build();
                c.output(appRow);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Some addition to above question :
When the same code i am running without join it is working properly but the time i am performing join i am getting the error. Can anyone please help me on this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you post more detailed error logs like a stack trace or a line number that throws the exception?

Comment: Thanks @ihji for responding , please find below error details :
INFO: SQL:
SELECT `emp`.`empno`, `emp`.`ename`, `emp`.`job`, `emp`.`mgr`, `emp`.`hiredate`, `emp`.`sal`, `emp`.`comm`, `emp`.`deptno`, `dept`.`deptno` AS `deptno0`, `dept`.`dname`, `dept`.`location`
FROM `beam`.`emp` AS `emp`
INNER JOIN `beam`.`dept` AS `dept` ON `emp`.`deptno` = `dept`.`deptno`


at com.nitesh.gcp.feature.beamSQL1.main (beamSQL1.java:55)

This basically fails when i am combining two PCollection into PCollectionTuple and performing join on the two tuple.
 output.apply( SqlTransform.query("join")

Comment: command used :
mvn compile exec:java -Pdirect-runner -Dexec.mainClass=com.nitesh.gcp.feature.beamSQL1 -Dexec.args=" --tempLocation=gs://dataflow-8431909583/tempsql --project="dataflowtest-233007""

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help much. Need to see full stack traces to find the source of the problem. Also try with other runners and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried with dataflow runner as well but getting the same issue while compiling.
I am not able to add full logs as the comment section does not allows me more the put everything here.

Comment: This was pom issue . Updating POM helped me to solve this.